# Vicryl suture not dissolving

Tags: surgery

I had surgery recently, the doctor said he used vicryl suture to close the wound. I understand that vicryl dissolves in 70 days, but it's been 80 days since my surgery and the suture is still there. Also, everytime I google vicryl, I see the thread is purple in color. However, the suture I received is white in color.

I am starting to have serious concerns about the situation as following -

1. What if the stitch is not vicryl, and will never dissolve
2. What if I get an infection from the mysterious thing (stitch) inside me.

P.S. I found a variant of vicryl called rapid vicryl which is white in color, but it is supposed to dissolve even sooner, in 42 days. Since my stitch has not dissolved, I guess it must not be rapid vicryl.

Comment: 70 days is probably an average - vicryl is absorbable and will eventually dissolve (might just take longer in some people - shorter in others)

Comment: Vicryl comes in both dyed (purple) and undyed (white); the purple is easier to see (thus work with) so purple is most often used when it's not someplace obvious. If the doctor told you it was vicryl (and if you're really worried, read his report), then it will ultimately dissolve; the amount of moisture a place has (e.g. the mouth) will affect the suture's rate of dissolution. Don't worry about it unless there is any sign of infection; if you do, go back to the doctor.